# extract parts of URL string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an object value/string that is a url. I need to extract the piece of the url that contains a unique identifier. How can this be done via regex?

Here is the example string:

```
http://images.example.com/examp/img/uuid/c49eccd1ddf1f4c341bf1d04140sdf7e261ae4014d422376cf9b293e6a8ad7/100/105/1.0
```

I am trying to extract just what is after uuid/ and before /100

Comment: Make this regex would be pretty straightforward, what have you tried so far?

Comment: `var uuid = url.match(/uuid\/([^/]+)/) [1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without having to write a regex. Avoiding regex for simple tasks is usually preferred. Something like this might help:

```
var str = window.location.href.split( "/uuid/" );
var yourAnswer = str[1].split( "/" );
yourAnswer = str[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var identifier=string.split("/")[6];
```

Simlly take out the stuff between the 5th and the 6th slash.

Answer (score 0):

if the unique ID is /c49eccd1ddf1f4c341bf1d04140sdf7e261ae4014d422376cf9b293e6a8ad7/

you can use this regex `'[a-z0-9]{62}'` which would mean, a 62 character interval of non-cap letters and numbers.

if you know the length is in between two values, lets say 50-70, you could type it like this: `'[a-z0-9]{50,70}'`

definetly @jonas-w answer is way better and does not require regexes.